# My minecraft launcher won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I tried to start my minecraft launcher, a little box would pop up and say it wouldn't launch and was caused by a corruption and that I had to reinstall minecraft. Whenever I did the same thing would happen. Could someone please help?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221611/minecraft-1-8-6-download-launcher-1-6-11-issues-vista-32-bit. While your system may be differant, the answer on that question is really the best answer we could give you, and is independant of platform, operating system or game version.

Comment: @Timelord64 I would disagree with that assessment; they're not even asking the same thing.

Comment: As I said, @Frank, my basis for it was the "fixing the corruption" issue. While the other question is rather long, OP's ultimate problem is that every time they download minecraft, it corrupts. Thats why I posted a comment, in case it did provide help to OP.

Comment: @Timelord64 Our stance on dupes is that they're only duplicates if they're asking the same thing; the answer being the same does not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the Minecraft.exe file as you have been doing. (I think you can skip this first step)
2. Right click on the start menu and select `Run` (see image below, and enter `%appdata%` in the highlighted area); Alternativley, if the start menu takes you to tile view, you can simply type "run" from the tile view and hit enter.
3. Open the directory called "Roaming"
4. Copy the .minecraft folder to your desktop (just in case)
5. Delete the folder named .minecraft
6. Download the game again from online

[image: Windows Run Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, *BEFORE* you reinstall, make certain that you have uninstalled and deleted *ALL* game files. Before you do this, I would strongly recommend backing up any world data files you wish to try to repair. If you use any resource packs and have an internet data limit, you should save those too.

Your game files are stored at

- [WINDOWS]: `%APPDATA%/Roaming/.minecraft`.
- [OS X]: `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`
- [Linux]: `/user/<USERNAME>/.minecraft`
- [MCPE]: (for completeness) `/sdcard/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`

Alternately you can choose to install it somewhere else and configure it to store its data files somewhere else.

Comment: You have a good answer, more details needed in this case IMO.... Still +1 for the different system locations...